# WPF Event to Command Binding in Parent Child DataGrid failing to bind Child DataGrid Events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I want to perform CRUD operations on hierarchical data in a DataGrid with Parent Child relationship in WPF. To show Child Grids I am using a Data Grid with a RowDetailsTemplate set to a StaticResource. As context I am using MVVM pattern with Prism Framework and Telerik controls.

I have put the two child Data Views in a Tab Control in a data template. The application displays the data perfectly. My problem is that events in the child grids are not being bound to the corresponding Delegate Commands in the ViewModel. I have tried to bind the events in the Child DataGrids in different ways to no avail (commented out in code below).

My suspicion is that it has something to do with the Prism ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel as the binding error I get in the Output Window does not reference my ViewModel as I would expect. (Location_14A... as opposed to LocationViewModel)

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'BeginEditCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Location_14A7828CEC09716B3DA7369A214EE4EE12A5B3DF727D10928AAFA56EF30AA046' (HashCode=59884855)'. BindingExpression:Path=SubBeginEditCommand; DataItem='Location_14A7828CEC09716B3DA7369A214EE4EE12A5B3DF727D10928AAFA56EF30AA046' (HashCode=59884855); target element is 'EventBinding' (HashCode=66128121); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

What is odd is that the Events bind perfectly in the Parent DataGrid, so I am sure I am overlooking something small.

My DataTemplate is as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate">
                <telerik:RadTabControl>
                    <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Bins">
                        <telerik:RadGridView Name ="bins"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Bins, Mode=TwoWay}">

                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="BeginningEdit">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding BeginEditCommand}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                            <!--<telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
                                <telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding BeginEditCommand}" EventName="BeginningEdit"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                            </telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>-->

                            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                        </telerik:RadGridView>
                    </telerik:RadTabItem>
                </telerik:RadTabControl>
            </DataTemplate>
```

My Parent Grid view is simply:

```
        <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Row ="0"
                             Name ="MainGridView"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding MainCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             SelectionMode="Extended"
                             RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailsTemplate}">

            <telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
                <telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding BeginEditCommand}" EventName="BeginningEdit"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>

            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Location Id" 
                                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                            IsReadOnly="True"/>
              <!--Removed for Bevity-->
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

I expect that when I begin editing in the Child DataGrid the Delegate Command is called, as it is when I begin editing in the Parent Data Grid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you actually show the code that uses the `ViewModelLocator` as you suspect it to cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single `BeginEditCommand` property that is defined in the same class as the `Bins` property that the `RadGridView` binds to, this binding should work in the `RowDetailsTemplate`:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.BeginEditCommand, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, the error I was making when I originally tried this option was not prefix the AncestorType correctly with telerik: So then I suppose its perfectly logical if couldn't find it in the visual tree. Stupid mistake..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are in the wrong datacontext inside the datagrid, at least I had very similar problems (coincidentally with Telerik and Prism). MM8 has one solution that might work but if relativesource doesn't work, another approach that worked for me was the introduction of a BindingProxy.
The idea is that you create a resource that holds nothing but the datacontext and that you then can reference this resource as static resource within the datagrid.

in my code it looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and the bindind would be:

```
{Binding Path=Data.BeginEditCommand, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}
```

the code of the binding proxy and the original idea comes from this site:
https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: This is a good idea which I will certainly come in handy. MM8's solution was a simple fix in this scenario as I was in the correct data context.